# Несовершенный вид к "обнародовать"

Tags: грамматика, аспектология

Считал, что глагол "обнародовать" двувидовой.
Написал фразу *"личную переписку не стал бы обнародовать"* - и полез проверять.
Увы, в словарях про несовершенный вид ничего не сказано.
Есть ли он вообще? И какой? А если нет, достаточное ли это основание использовать глагол как двувидовой?!

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Пусть другие отвечают, но по крайней мере скажу, что мне слух не резануло, воспринял это как совершенно правильное.

Answer (score 3):

Изредка несовершеннный вид этого глагола требуется, и в книгах можно найти примеры его употребления как двухвидового, по запросу "*всякий-раз-обнародовать*" или "*обнародует*" (в контексте, где явно не будущее время). Когда-то варианты "**обнародовывать**" и даже "**обнародывать**" (как упрощение первого в интересах произношения) всерьёз рассматривались (Труды Я. К. Грота. II. Филологические разыскания (1852-1892) https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=KBB4BAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA717&img=1&zoom=3&ots=RzlCNJXBkI&sig=ACfU3U0a1QJgMFRxt2DJBDVUkriBFIelnA&w=1280 ).

Возможно, вопрос о дозволении вариантов несовершенного вида до сих пор не закрыт, если где-то со ссылкой на школьные олимпиады в загадках рассматриваются даже производные причастия несовершенного вида: [http://руяз.рф/zagadki/08-Morfologia/02-Glagol/Otvet-7.html](http://%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8F%D0%B7.%D1%80%D1%84/zagadki/08-Morfologia/02-Glagol/Otvet-7.html)

С похожим случаем "*опробовать*" решено было в пользу двухвидовости (вместо "*опробовывать*" или "*опробывать*"). То же с "исповедовать" (в смысле исповеди).